# BigQuery : Subquery SELECT A WHERE B MAX AND C = Parent Alias

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I hope you having a safe day!

I was struggling with this BigQuery SQL, I am not expert in BigQuery.

**This is how data looks like**
[image]

**This is what I tried**

```
SELECT
  D.symbol,
  (SELECT
      exchange
    FROM `wingspan-staging.tardis.derivative_ticker` a
      JOIN (SELECT
          MAX(t.funding_rate) AS max_fr
        FROM `wingspan-staging.tardis.derivative_ticker` t
        WHERE t.symbol = D.symbol) b
        ON b.max_fr = a.funding_rate
    WHERE a.symbol = D.symbol) AS max_exchange,
  (SELECT
      AVG(funding_rate)
    FROM `wingspan-staging.tardis.derivative_ticker`
    WHERE exchange = 'ftx'
    AND symbol = D.symbol) AS ftx,
  (SELECT
      AVG(funding_rate)
    FROM `wingspan-staging.tardis.derivative_ticker`
    WHERE exchange = 'deribit'
    AND symbol = D.symbol) AS deribit,
  (SELECT
      AVG(funding_rate)
    FROM `wingspan-staging.tardis.derivative_ticker`
    WHERE exchange = 'bitmex'
    AND symbol = D.symbol) AS bitmex,
  MAX(funding_rate) - MIN(funding_rate) AS diff
FROM `wingspan-staging.tardis.derivative_ticker` D
GROUP BY symbol
```

**This is how I want**
[image]

Currently everything is working except the second column `max_exchange`, if I run this code, it takes so long to complete.

```
  (SELECT
      exchange
    FROM `wingspan-staging.tardis.derivative_ticker` a
      JOIN (SELECT
          MAX(t.funding_rate) AS max_fr
        FROM `wingspan-staging.tardis.derivative_ticker` t
        WHERE t.symbol = D.symbol) b
        ON b.max_fr = a.funding_rate
    WHERE a.symbol = D.symbol) AS max_exchange
```

If I run this way, the system shows Error `Scalar subquery produced more than one element` and If I add `LIMIT 1` the actual error comes in `Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.`

**What I actually want to do is...**
First I want to group the first column `symbol` and then want to identify the highest `funding_rate` containing `exchange` name within the `symbol`. Next three columns are average of exchanges and last one is the difference between maximum and minimum of `funding_rate`.

This is may be simple thing for you, but I am struggling since 2 days.
Can anyone help on this, how can I optimize this thing?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please explain more clearly the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Sure, First I want to group first column ````symbol```` and then want to identify the highest ````funding_rate```` containing ````exchange```` name within the symbol. Next three columns are average of exchanges and last one is the difference between maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got you right. You should share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the desired result.

You could try to rewriting the query like this, using windows functions:

You may not get the desired result, but you can get an idea of ​​how to rewrite the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       D.symbol,
       FIRST_VALUE(exchange) OVER (PARTITION BY D.symbol ORDER BY funding_rate DESC) AS max_exchange,
       AVG(CASE WHEN exchange = 'ftx' THEN funding_rate END) OVER (PARTITION BY D.symbol) AS ftx,
       AVG(CASE WHEN exchange = 'deribit' THEN funding_rate END) OVER (PARTITION BY D.symbol) AS deribit,
       AVG(CASE WHEN exchange = 'bitmex' THEN funding_rate END) OVER (PARTITION BY D.symbol) AS bitmex,
       FIRST_VALUE(funding_rate) OVER (PARTITION BY D.symbol ORDER BY funding_rate DESC) 
           - FIRST_VALUE(funding_rate) OVER (PARTITION BY D.symbol ORDER BY funding_rate ASC) AS diff 
FROM `wingspan-staging.tardis.derivative_ticker` D;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your query worked like charm. I will follow the minimal reproducible example in the future.

Comment: You are welcome @KhaledBinAmir! I'm glad I helped you.